# asyncio requests (aiohttp, aioftp, etc) in a class-based design

Tags: python, oop, python-asyncio, aiohttp, asyncssh

I am trying to move my codebase over to asyncio and aiohttp, aioftp, etc. I've been led to believe that the clients should be reused for multiple requests instead of opening a new one each time. For instance, if I have a multi-part code that requires 2 GETs then a POST, I should use the same aiohttp.ClientSession() for all 3.

My problem is - I have a class-based pattern that abstracts away the FTP, HTTP, etc. operations and I'm having trouble converting it to something compatible with asyncio that preserves the original pattern.

For instance, let's say I have:

```py
class Task1:
   def __init__(self, method):
class Task1:
   def __init__(self, method):
      self.method = method

   async def doTask(self):
      status = await self.method.send("blah")
      status2 = await self.method.send("blah2")
      status3 = await self.method.send("blah3")
      if status < 300 and status2 < 300 and status3 < 300:
         return 200
      else:
         return 500

class Task2:
   def __init__(self, method):
      self.method = method

   async def doTask(self):
      status = await self.method.send("{\"myjson\":1}")
      status2 = await self.method.send("something else")
      if status < 300 and status2 < 300:
         return 200
      else:
         return 500

class HTTP:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    async def send(self, data):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
            async with client.post(self.url, data=data) as resp:
                return resp.status

class FTP:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    async def send(self, data):
        bytestream = io.BytesIO(data.encode('utf-8'))
        status = 500
        while True:
            try:
                async with aioftp.Client.context(self.url, 21, "", "") as client:
                    bytestream.seek(0)
                    async with client.upload_stream("data.txt") as stream:
                        while True:
                            data = bytestream.read(256)
                            if not data:
                                break
                            await stream.write(data)
                        status = 200
                        break
            except ConnectionResetError:
                return status
        return status
            

async def main(method,task):
    mymethod = None
    if method == "ftp":
        mymethod = FTP("www.some-endpoint.com")
    elif method == "http":
        mymethod = HTTP("https://webhook.site/5d1341ad-8b1b-4e4d-a61d-0756b009964e")

    mytask = None
    if task == "1":
        mytask= Task1(mymethod)
    elif task == "2":
        mytask= Task2(mymethod)

    if mytask is not None and mymethod is not None:
        res = await mytask.doTask()
        if res == 200:
            print("done")
        else:
            print("fail")
```

The way this code is currently set up, when main runs it would call `await mytask.doTask()` which would open up either multiple `aiohttp.ClientSession()` or multiple `aioftp.Client()` which I've been discouraged from doing. I'd love for only one to open up, but I'm worried that would require undoing all of the abstraction I have set up right now.

Other things I've seen involve implementing `__aenter()__` and `__aexit()__` for each method (HTTP, FTP) and instantiating the client there but I don't know if that's proper in python, and my current implementation don't really work. But it would look something like:

```py
   if mytask is not None and mymethod is not None:
      async with mytask.method.client:
        res = await mytask.doTask()
        if res == 200:
            print("done")
        else:
            print("fail")
```

Where each method implements its own property called `client` that is call-able in an abstract way from main. Trying to do this, I keep getting AttributeErrors on **aenter** which would mean the client isn't even getting set up, as in this example:

```py
    async def __aenter__(self):
        self.client = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        return self
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? How to architect an abstract class-based asyncio server?

Edit: Based on a comment I did a quick hack of creating a global dictionary with keys of method and values of client. Then use just the client handle in the `async with` and pass that down to the actual method classes. Here's an example, though I think there's some jank - I wish I didn't need to modify the `doTask()` signature to pass a client variable down but I'm still investigating.

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import aioftp
import io
import sys

class Task1:
   def __init__(self, method):
      self.method = method

   async def doTask(self, client):
      self.method.client = client
      status = await self.method.send("blah")
      status2 = await self.method.send("blah2")
      status3 = await self.method.send("blah3")
      if status < 300 and status2 < 300 and status3 < 300:
         return 200
      else:
         return 500

class Task2:
   def __init__(self, method):
      self.method = method

   async def doTask(self, client):
      self.method.client = client
      status = await self.method.send("{\"myjson\":1}")
      status2 = await self.method.send("something else")
      if status < 300 and status2 < 300:
         return 200
      else:
         return 500

class HTTP:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        ClientList['http'] = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        self.client = None

    async def send(self, data):
        async with self.client.post(self.url, data=data) as resp:
            return resp.status

class FTP:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        ClientList['ftp'] = aioftp.Client.context(self.url, 21, "dlpuser", "rNrKYTX9g7z3RgJRmxWuGHbeu")
        self.client = None

    async def send(self, data):
        bytestream = io.BytesIO(data.encode('utf-8'))
        status = 500
        while True:
            try:
                bytestream.seek(0)
                async with self.client.upload_stream("data.txt") as stream:
                    while True:
                        data = bytestream.read(256)
                        if not data:
                            break
                        await stream.write(data)
                    status = 200
                    break
            except ConnectionResetError:
                return status
        return status
            

async def main(method,task):
    global ClientList
    ClientList = {}

    mymethod = None
    if method == "ftp":
        mymethod = FTP("ftp.someendpoint.com")
    elif method == "http":
        mymethod = HTTP("https://someendpoint.com")

    mytask = None
    if task == "1":
        mytask= Task1(mymethod)
    elif task == "2":
        mytask= Task2(mymethod)

    if mytask is not None and mymethod is not None:
        async with ClientList[method] as client:
            res = await mytask.doTask(client)
            if res == 200:
                print("done")
            else:
                print("fail")
```

Comment: How about some kind of pool (one for each protocol). At beginning of `send` a Client(Session) object is retrieved from the pool and given back at the end. Finally the pool can be closed and/or objects in it can be closed if they are unused for a certain amount of time.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77517846/edit) your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with test data demonstrating your problem. The (incomplete) error doesn't appear to originate from the example code you posted - which also in invalid Python (e.g. `if method is "ftp:"`)

Comment: Ran the updated code with `python text.py http 1` - you'll need to put your own HTTP and FTP endpoints though

Comment: @michael-butscher are you using the term pool formally or informally here? I know that asyncio provides a pool management function so I wanted to be sure I understood you correctly if you meant that or not. Or, for example, do you mean something like (to dumb it down) a dictionary that stores one client session per method, e.g. {"http":aiohttp.ClientSession()}? 

If so that might work, though I'd have to do some special stuff to make the classes instantiate their client session object and put it into the pool?

Comment: I meant an informal pool. I wasn't sure if multiple Client(Session) objects for each protocol would be needed at the same time. If not, it can be a simple dictionary mapping protocol to object plus functionality to create and close each object when required.

Comment: @michael-butscher thanks, updated the post with your feedback. It does work but I'm a bit mixed on whether I like the elegance of my specific interpretation of what you said haha. But it's definitely enough to get up and going - at that point I'll update the post if I can figure out a way to make it cleaner.